# Material-ui combobox not showing the required data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am so new to JavaScript and React and I have a beginner level question. Here I have tried to fetch some data from an API and eliminate it to what exactly I need (full name of countries and their short version).
I would like to make the list of countries in a material UI combobox and show them in two ways:
first to show the names completely in case of opening the list of countries.
second to show their short form like (USA) in case of choosing a country from the list.
how can I make the second goal possible? and why at line 47, I cant pars-in country.value ?
thanks in advance for your time.

```
import './App.css';
import {FormControl, TextField} from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab';


function App() {

  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(['worldwide']);


  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountriesData = async() => {
      await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const countries =data.map((country) => (
          {
            name: country.country,
            value: country.countryInfo.iso2
          }
        ))
        setCountries(countries)
      })
    }
    getCountriesData()

  }, [])


  const onCountryChange = async (event) => {
    const countryCode = event.target.value

    setCountry(countryCode)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app__header">
        <h1>
          Country names!
        </h1>
        <FormControl className="app__dropDown">
          <Autocomplete
              options={countries}
              getOptionLabel={(country) => country.name}
              style={{ width: 200 }}
              onChange={onCountryChange}
              renderInput={country => (
                <TextField
                  {...country}
                  label="Choose a Country"
                  variant="outlined"
                  placeholder="Choose a Country"
                />
            )}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </div>
      

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I recommend you to update the question title

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please have a look at the how-to guides when writing the question. Your title is not very good, as it doesn't describe your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using both `async/await` and `then` here, just pick one, for ex.:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getCountriesData = () => {
     fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const countries = data.map((country) => (
          {
            name: country.country,
            value: country.countryInfo.iso2
          }
        ))
        setCountries(countries)
      })
    }
    getCountriesData()

  }, [])
```